# Writing Java server to handle multiple simultaneous clients

Tags: java, client, selector, executor

I need some advice in building a Java server that handles multiple clients at the same time. The clients need to remain connected for fairly long periods of time. I'm currently using blocking IO and spawning a thread to read from each client that connects to the server, but this is obviously not scalable.

I've found a few options, including using Selector or Executor with fixed size thread pools. I am not too familiar with either one, so which would be the best solution here? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that your solution is not scalable? How many simultaneous clients are you expecting?

Comment: I guess I was underestimating the performance of spawning numerous Threads. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of scalable. The system you have described with a single thread per connection is scalable up to hundreds may be even a couple of thousand concurrent connections, it will hit a wall at some point.

Your question says that your clients connect and stay connected for an extended period of time, it would be possible to have a single IO thread to handle the reading and writing, but have the processing of the request dispatched to another thread using an Executor.

There are frameworks/servers that are already written to handle this sort of event driven design. Have a look at:

- [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) recently used by [twitter in there query server](http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/04/twitter-search-is-now-3x-faster_1656.html)
- [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) (not to be confused with Netty) capable of NIO and very scalable, might be to HTTP focused
- [MINA](http://mina.apache.org/)
- [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/)

It's worth noting that the world is full of failed startups & software products that had really scalable architecture. Scaling is a nice problem to have, better to have the problem than not to have it and no customers.

Answer (score 0):

using multiple threads is scalable. Apache for example does this, and some sites using it get many visitors. However, another approach would indeed be using selector, though I have no experience using it.

After all, this seems like a question, which religion is the best.

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot of framework for this kind of job, examples

1. [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)
2. [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Independently of scalability every server application has it's limits. By using blocking IO, one of your limits will be the number of threads that the VM can spawn because the approach you take is "one-thread-per-client". With NIO (of which Selector is one of the classes), the approach is "one-thread-per-request" which will run out of threads much latter.

Horizontal scalability ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_vs._vertically ) of your app will not depend on either of these choices.